# Enable Partner User Button Apex

Tags: trigger, partner-portal, community

So i've been looking around on the communities documentation, and I haven't found anything on this button and Apex. I'm trying to select the 'Manage External User's' and 'Enable as Partner' in an Apex Trigger, but I haven't been able to find anything on what the fields are actually called.

Anybody know this off hand? Suggestions are very welcome!!

Comment: What I can tell you is that it doesn't work that way. When you manage an external user for the 1st time, your trigger would essentially be creating a portal or community user (either customer or partner) from a contact. Think of it as a different UI than the one used in Setup for Managing and creating Users. If you know how to create a User in a test class from a contact, then you know what you need to do for the code in a trigger.

Comment: What the OP is asking about is NOT creating the Community Users but enabling the Account as a Partner Account. On the Account it is the button Manage External Account > Enable As Partner. What this does is it creates the Roles for that Partner Account, and then sets IsPartner on Account to true.

Comment: So I think [this post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/81916/programatically-create-partner-community-accounts-using-apex-api) may shed some light on the enabling the Partner.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need access to those buttons to provision (create) a Communities Partner User via Apex. Its simpler than that.

## Part 1: Recap... Overview of Communities Profiles

Once you purchase the appropriate Communities licenses from Salesforce.com, you will have access to Communities Profiles. The one you want to focus on is the 'Partner Community User' which has the 'Partner Community' license type. Clone it, make it your own. The important part is having the profile with the 'Partner Community' license type.

## Part 2: Create the Communities Partner User via Apex

Remember that Communities Users are bound to a Contact. This exercise is very straightforward, then. We start at the Contact, pull out information required by a User record, and insert a new User record with the 'Partner Community' profile.

Functional beta code included below. You could do this exercise in a Trigger, sure, but I envisioned this code sitting behind a button on the Contact record which is why I've written the code the way that I have (global+webservice called from simple javascript button on Contact, pass in record ID). It should be a trivial exercise to understand my code below and re-purpose for your Trigger. Its just Apex. Improve, modify, re-purpose... steal with pride.

```
global class CreateCommunityUser {

  WebService static string createUserFromContact(String contactId) {
    Contact objectContact = [SELECT FirstName,LastName,Email,AccountId 
                       FROM Contact Where Email <> null AND Id =: contactId LIMIT 1];
    try {
      //Select community profile that you want to assign
      Profile pf = [SELECT Id FROM profile 
                    WHERE name='Super Interesting Communities Profile' LIMIT 1];
      //Create user 
      User newCommunitiesUser = new User(contactId=objectContact.Id, 
                          username=objectContact.Email, 
                          firstname=objectContact.FirstName,
                          lastname=objectContact.LastName, 
                          email=objectContact.Email,
                          communityNickname = objectContact.LastName + '_'+Math.random(),
                          alias = string.valueof(objectContact.FirstName.substring(0,1) + 
                                  objectContact.LastName.substring(0,1) + Math.random() ).substring(0,5), 
                          profileid = pf.Id, emailencodingkey='UTF-8',
                          languagelocalekey='en_US', 
                          localesidkey='en_US', 
                          timezonesidkey='America/Los_Angeles');                  
      insert newCommunitiesUser;
      return 'true';
    } catch(DMLException ex) {
        if(ex.getDMLMessage(0).contains('Duplicate Username')) {
          return '[ERROR] Cannot enable communities access, a user with this email address already exists.';
        }
        return ex.getDMLMessage(0);
    }
  }
}
```

## Final Thoughts

The 'hardest part' is enforcing uniqueness in the fields (e.g. nickname and alias) that require uniqueness. There are different (better) ways to solve the uniqueness requirement, but hey... beta code.

Comment: That is a really nice post on enabling community users via code, but what the OP is asking for is how to make the click of the button on Account for Manage External Account > Enable as Partner be able to happen through code.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I just tested this in a Flow and it works well. Just set Account.IsPartner to True. As per the other post mentioned, it must be done after the Account is created, not during the Account creation process.