# programatically create Partner Community Accounts using Apex / API

Tags: partner-communities, automation, portal

Our sandbox is refreshed often. To re-create the portal environment on the sandbox entails number of manual steps.

**Details**
I have a seven test accounts and  each account has exactly one contact. Recreating this data is easily scripted after a sandbox refresh.

I would now like to automate the enabling of each of these seven accounts as a partner community and the associated contact for each account as a community user.

Is there an api to automate some or part of this? Is this even possible?

Comment: It's not an area I've worked in too much, but is this automation of Manage External User->Enable Customer User on the Contact record?

Comment: @PhilHawthorn I think, automating `Manage External Account` > `Enable As Partner` on the Account record...

Comment: I'm out then....definitely not something i've worked with

Answer (score 6):

To enable the accounts as partner accounts, set the 'IsPartner' field to true after creating the account (it cannot be done during creation, only by update).

```
Account partnerAccount= new Account(
    Name = 'theAccount',
);
Database.insert(partnerAccount);

partnerAccount.IsPartner = true;
update partnerAccount;
```

Next step is to add the contacts/users. I think the only known way is to just create a Contact under the partner account, then create a User (with the right partner profile) and link the user to the contact by filling the ContactId field.

```
//Create contact
Contact theContact = new Contact(
    FirstName = 'Test',
    Lastname = 'Contact',
    AccountId = partnerAccount.Id,
    Email = 'test@test.com'
);

Insert(theContact);

//Create user
Profile portalProfile = [select Id from Profile where UserType = 'PowerPartner' limit 1];

User theUser = new User(
    Username = 'test123@test.com',
    ContactId = theContact.Id,
    ProfileId = portalProfile.Id,
    Alias = 'test123',
    Email = 'test123@test.com',
    EmailEncodingKey = 'UTF-8',
    LastName = 'McTesty',
    CommunityNickname = 'test123',
    TimeZoneSidKey = 'America/Los_Angeles',
    LocaleSidKey = 'en_US',
    LanguageLocaleKey = 'en_US'
);
insert(theUser);
```

Comment: I just did similar using a Flow and it works well. I thought I would have to resort to code, but everything works nicely (and no, this client will not be creating bulk partner users).

Comment: @JodieM that's good to know, tnx!